# Expanded usercards do not expand any more

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, privileges, user-card

It seems that [expanded usercards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) are broken network-wide. [For instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49149896/1544337):

[image]

This user has well over 1,000 reputation, but the usercard misses shadow and does not expand on hovering. The issue also exists on Biblical Hermeneutics with the default beta theme; it seems to be network-wide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) page,

> An expanded usercard is only available if there are at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile. When your profile is long enough to show an expanded usercard a drop shadow effect will be shown on your avatar.

The [specified user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) "About Me" section is empty, so it is not expanding.

---

So it is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Thanks, that explained it. I still suspect something changed though, because I thought I used to have an expanded card as well on some sites. My profile consists solely of HTML tags, perhaps these are not counted any more. Anyway, no way to check I suppose. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Keelan Did you check this for accounts where the "About Me" section contains more than 28 characters? E.g. [Arulkumar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312043/arulkumar) [Rand al'Thor ](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/17/rand-althor). I don't see expanded user cards anywhere.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I'm not sure what you mean. For me it works as described in this post.

Comment: @Keelan My mistake; they work only when you hover over the profile *picture*, not the other parts of the profile link.